# Putting environment variables to env.yml

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have these config files serverless.yml and env.yml and when I try to deploy, I get an error. The Lambda functions cannot be deployed.

serverless.yml

```
---omitted---

provider:
  environment: ${file(env.yml):${self:custom.stage}}

---omitted---
```

env.yml

```
---omitted---

dev:
  keyzero: "valuezero"
  keyone:
    keyoneone: "valueoneone"
    keyonetwo: "valueonetwo"
    keyonethree: "valueonethree"

---omitted---
```

ERROR:

> Serverless: Operation failed!
>
> Serverless Error ---------------------------------------
>
> An error occurred: PingLambdaFunction - Value of property Variables
>   must be an object with String (or simple type) properties.

Comment: You should also provide the snippet of your serverless.yml, where you actually define the PingLambdaFunction. The issue seems to related to how you map those environment values to this specific Lambda.

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables cannot be an object. They are simply key-value pairs where `value` should be of primitive types (i.e. string/number/boolean/null).

Your `keyone` variable is an object which is why it throws the error "Variables must be an object with String (or simple type) properties".

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify which value from `env.yml` you want to use.

In your example, if you want to get the value of `keyonetwo`, you'd use

```
${file(env.yml):${opt:stage}.keyone.keyonetwo}
```

Which would yield `valueonetwo`

Also, checkout the [documentation](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/#referencing-environment-variables) and how they reference environment variables.

You need to set each environment variable, so you'd need

```
provider:
  environment:
    keyoneone: ${file(env.yml):${opt:stage}.keyone.keyoneone}
    keyonetwo: ${file(env.yml):${opt:stage}.keyone.keyonetwo}
```